# keydown() and holding in a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

```
$(document).keydown(myOnKeyDownFunction);
```

I notice that in Chrome 10.0 and Firefox 3.6 (both in Ubuntu), after registering a listener for keydown, the callback is invoked once immediately, followed by a short delay, and then triggered again repeatedly until the key is released.  For my current project, this sure makes my life easier... but can I expect it to behave like that for all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a (possibly out-of-date) summary of how various browsers handle key presses and keyboard auto-repeat at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: +1. That page is not out of date. The author (Jan Wolter) still updates it and it has information on current browsers.

Comment: Does jQuery does any magic to normalize some of that, though?

Comment: @keithjgrant: Yes, jQuery normalizes some of the key handling issues. Specifically, it normalizes key codes and char codes into the `which` property of its key events. However, it does nothing about other differences such as autorepeat and whether or not `keypress` events are fired for non-prinatble keys.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the same for all browsers since this event should mirror the keyboards repeat buffer.

Try to put your cursor in any text field and look how the flow of letters are when you just hold down a key - it is exactly like your describe.

Comment: it _isn't_ the same for all browsers.